# How to store multiple language data in database (MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have one table of items, let's call it ITEMS. Now I need to store the name of each item in multiple languages. I am looking for most efficient way to do this. So far I have these possible solutions below, but I really would like to pick one for some specific reason.

For question sake, lets keep things simple, structure of ITEMS table:

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY
name VARCHAR(20)
```

Now first easiest solution would probably be adding columns for each language in ITEMS table, e.g. name_english, name_german, name_spanish, etc... But this would probably involve a lot of work in PHP when adding new languages.

Second solution - I would create table LANGS:

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
language VARCHAR(10)
```

and table ITEMS_LANGS:

```
id_items INT
id_langs INT
translated_name VARCHAR(20)
```

so each time I would have to join the tables ITEMS and ITEMS_LANGS, but it would be much more easier to add new languages.

Which solution should I choose, or do you have better solution ? Thanks in advance, hope I have explained my problem in enough detail.

Comment: second option is lot more easier to manage than the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is better if:

- you'll need to add new languages
- you'll need to support multi-language in other fields of your database (in this case id_items has no sense, you need a global entities id).

I'll change  ITEMS_LANGS by TEXTS (more generic):

```
id_text INT
id_entity INT
id_langs INT
translated_name VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: I'll want to add more languages in future. Just for clarification - would I have to create index for each of the columns - id_text, id_entity and id_langs ? Because I would have to use all 3 of them in query ...

Comment: Just one INDEX (unique) for the 3 columns: id_text, id_entity and id_langs

Answer (score 0):

I would create one table for ITEMS as you describe at the beginning, with an id as the primary key and then separate tables for each language (same with id as a foreign key and name).

This will make it easier for you to add different language / remove some / add items and still have a fallback value if the name does not exist in the language you need...etc...